# asp.net mvc 3 dependency injection ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, access-specifier

I want to ask something about asp.net mvc 3 dependency injection ninject.

### Here is my Interface,

```
 public interface IRegistration<T>
{
    bool Registration(T Entity); 
}
```

---

This is ClsMembers class.

```
  public class ClsMembers:IRegistration<Member>
    {
        private SmileWorkDbEntities db;

        public ClsMembers()
        {
            db = new SmileWorkDbEntities();
        }

        public bool Registration(Member member)
        {
            db.Members.Add(member);

            if (db.SaveChanges() != 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public int GetMemberId(string username, string pwd)
        {
            var Mem = (from m in db.Members where m.Member_username == username && m.Member_password == pwd select m).FirstOrDefault();
            return Mem.Member_id;
        }
    }
```

---

here is my controller,

```
public class MembersRegistrationController : Controller
{
    IRegistration<Member> ireg1;        

    public MembersRegistrationController(IRegistration<Member> _ireg1)
    {
        ireg1 = _ireg1;            
    }

    public ActionResult MemberRegistration()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MemberRegistration(Member m)
    {
        if(ireg1.Registration(m))
        {                

            return RedirectToAction("MemberProfileRegistration", new {mId = i });
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }       

}
```

---

Everything is ok... but i cannot access GetMemberId() method.. pls tell me how can i access GetMemberId() from my controller...

Regard,
MinThitTun

Answer (score 2):

Modify your `IRegistration` interface by adding `int GetMemberId(string username, string pwd)` method:

```
public interface IRegistration<T>
{
    bool Registration(T Entity);
    int GetMemberId(string username, string pwd);
}
```

After all, I thing you should read [Interfaces (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx)

**UPDATE:**

```
public interface IMembersRepository
{
    int GetMemberId(string username, string password);
    // Other stuff related to members...
}

public class MembersRepository : IMembersRepository
{
    private SmileWorkDbEntities db = new SmileWorkDbEntities();

    public int GetMemberId(string username, string password)
    {
        var Mem = (from m in db.Members where m.Member_username == username && m.Member_password == pwd select m).FirstOrDefault();
        return Mem.Member_id;
    }
    // Other stuff related to members...
}

public class MembersRegistrationController : Controller
{
    IRegistration<Member> ireg1;        
    IMembersRepository membersRepository;

    public MembersRegistrationController(IRegistration<Member> _ireg1, IMembersRepository memRepository)
    {
        ireg1 = _ireg1;            
        membersRepository = memRepository;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks... but GetMemberId(string username, string pwd) method will not contain in every class.. so i didn't add in the interface.... so do u have any idea.. ? pls

Comment: So simply put `GetMemberId` in another interface for example `IMembersRepository` and then, pass it as a constructor parameter to controllers.